# Error: Property 'customApplicationComponents' not valid in version 43.0

Tags: community, sandbox

I have recently changed my salesforce application version from 42.0 to 43.0, getting below while trying to deploy the application.

Error: Property 'customApplicationComponents' not valid in version 43.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution, we have to use componentList instead of customApplicationComponents.

Reference: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.212.0.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_customapplication.htm

```
 <componentList>
    <alignment>left</alignment>
    <components>MyComponent</components>
    </componentList>
```